# WorkLight 6.2 - How to check previous notification messages which were sent in WorkLight console?

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

We are currently using Worklight 6.2 for our project. We are able to successfully send broadcast notifications. However, the basic reporting in the worklight console under the Push Notifications tab does not show any data regarding the broadcast notifications that have been sent. It appears that the reporting is only for notifications where device(s) will subscribe to an event source. Is that correct? Since there is no event source for broadcast notifications, is there no way to get the basic reporting ( # of messages sent, platform, number of subscribed users ) etc. in the worklight console for broadcast notifications?

If additional reporting is needed, is the only way to get it from the notification_proc table (we will not be using BIRT)? and create a custom page for the user or is there any out of the box provision to show more in the worklight console itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For tag-based notifications (this includes broadcast notifications), there is currently no visual indicator in either Worklight Console (via the Push Notifications tab), or Worklight Operational Analytics Platform.

This information is currently not stored in the database, but this may change in a future release.

Feel free to submit a feature request so that the product managers could take it into account for future releases: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/help/

Comment: Thanks Idan. Will submit a feature request.